# How do I rewrite a domain to a specific URL in a different domain using nginx?

Tags: nginx

I have a domain that I need to rewrite to point to a specific path in a different domain using nginx like this:

domain2.com --> https://stage.domain1.com/web/#/45MKzL7H

Both domains are pointed to the same host (DNS). Here is my nginx default.conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain1.com domain2.com;

    if ($host = 'domain2.com') {
      rewrite ^ https://stage.domain1.com/web/#/45MKzL7H;
    }

    rewrite ^/web/config/config.json /web/config/aws_stage.json;

    if ($request_uri = '/health-check') {
      return 200 "";
    }

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
      rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /web {
      rewrite ^/web(/.*)$ $1 last;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use separate `server` blocks for each domain.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain2.com;
    return 301 https://stage.domain1.com/web/#/45MKzL7H;
}
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain1.com;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.